# Map class property to view rendering on razor view?

Tags: glass-mapper

I'm trying to créate a carousel and i have a `PlayerCard` model that will work as a slide for my carousel. Then i have an interface `ICarousel` that has the main fields of the carousel and a `PlayersCarousel` that will implement the interface.

Something like this:

```
[SitecoreType(TemplateId = "{5B0B5442-D005-49A1-84DD-56788DCCD315}")]
    public class PlayersCarousel : SitecoreGlassMap<ICarouselV2>
    {
        public virtual IEnumerable<PlayerCard> Items { get; set; }
        public override void Configure()
        {
            Map(x=> x.AutoMap());
        }
    }

    public interface ICarouselV2
    {
        string BackgroundColor { get; set; }
        bool IsArrowHidden { get; set; }
        bool IsBulletHidden { get; set; }
        int AnimationTime { get; set; }
        int ItemsPerSlide { get; set; }
    }
```

Now, the `PlayerCard` is an ítem on sitecore that is mapped to a view rendering (named `Player Card`).
The razor view `PlayersCarousel.cshtml` will have this:

```
@inherits GlassView<PlayersCarousel>
@using ConexioFC.Models

@*------ I don't know what goes here--------*@
```

My question is how do i map the `Ítems` property of `PlayersCarousel` with the view rendering `Player Card`?

I'm using Glass.Mapper v4 with all this.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that you are looking for a way of mapping sub-items of a particular parent in the tree. You can use **Sitecore query** for mapping your `Items` property:

```
[SitecoreQuery("./*[@@templateid='tid']", IsRelative = true)]
public virtual IEnumerable<PlayerCard> Items { get; set; }
```

Please, check this Glass tutorial for more details: http://www.glass.lu/Blog/GettingChildItems

### Edit

You can iterate though your items in the view like that:

```
<div class="my-component">
    @foreach(var item in Model.Items)
    {  
        <div class="component-item-body">
            <p>@item.Text</p>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Comment: I know how to map child items but i don't know how to use those child items on the parent razor view and represent the child view render on the razor view

Comment: So model.Items does not give you a iEnumerable list?

Comment: Yes... `Model.Items` does give a `IEnumerable` list, what i'm asking is how to write the code on the `cshtml` razor view to output the corresponding view rendering of each item of the `Model.Items` list

Comment: I know that i can iterate over the Items... but how do i associate the viewrender on sitecore with each item...? that's my main question.

Comment: @Phoenix_uy can you follow this tutorial on how to set up a controller rendering? http://www.joe-stevens.com/2014/09/07/sitecore-mvc-tutorial-controller-renderings/